# Selenium webElement equals: does it compare the state of the element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

how does equals work on webElement, can I use it to check if the same element has been completely loaded?

For elements with animation, would equals return true imply the element returned by findElement at different time stamp are identical in look?

Say
webElemenet ele1 = driver.findElement(By.class("loading"));
sleep(10);
webElemenet ele2 = driver.findElement(By.class("loading"));

Would ele1.equals(ele2) == true, imply the element is completely loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The `equal` method indicates if two web elements are referring to the same instance of an HTML element in the page.

Whether the content of the HTML elements are different or not has no impact.

So no you can't use it to check the state of an element.

To check the state of an element, you'll have to read the attributes/properties or the text content.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the element returned is not null indicates that the element exists in the DOM (document object model).  Loading of the element would be complete, however there can sometimes be another hidden web element deliberately blocking access to the element until the page has completely loaded or ajax controls are finished processing.  For that, you'd need to check its clickable status through a fluent wait command.